# How can I execute multiple procedures continuously?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, php

Here is my code:

```
$query = "CALL user_top_categories_score(?, 'ALL', 0, 1)";
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute([$user_id]);
$category = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = "CALL user_top_tags_score(?, 'ALL', 0, 3)";
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute([$user_id]);
$tags = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It throws this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php:71 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php(71): PDO->prepare('CALL user_top_t...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\application\other.php(24): user->index() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\index.php(152): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php on line 71

Also I've used `closeCursor()` right after `fetchAll()`, based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17582620/6381081). But sadly it throws a new  error:

> Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 9. Packet size=7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php on line 72
>
> Warning: PDO::prepare(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php on line 72
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php:72 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php(72): PDO->prepare('CALL user_top_t...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\application\other.php(24): user->index() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\index.php(152): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\user.php on line 72

Any idea how can I fix the problem?

---

**Noted1:** Each of queries above work separately. I mean, when I call a single procedure, it works as well.

**Noted2:** Each procedure returns a result set. I mean there is a `SELECT` statement in those procedures, which may return multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $sth->close() after finishing the execute and fetch* calls.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty answer here would be to do the following

- prepare each query once
- prepare each query in separate statement handles
- call your execute and save result sets in separate arrays

LIke this

```
$query = "CALL user_top_categories_score(?, 'ALL', 0, 1)";
$topcat_sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

$query = "CALL user_top_tags_score(?, 'ALL', 0, 3)";
$toptag_sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

$topcat_sth->execute([$user_id]);
$topcat_rs = $topcat_sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$toptag_sth->execute([$user_id]);
$toptag_rs = $toptag_sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

...
```

Comment: I don't think this will help for the second time.  close() is missing.

Comment: Thank you ... but there is still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following works for me in most of the instances I've come across.The problem is that MySQL sends an extra rowset and thus remains open.

So after your procedure:

```
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->nextRowset();
```

In the case of multiple row results

```php
if($stmt->rowCount())  // Don't depend on this for row count in select, but it will return 0 if no rows were found. Anything else is true.
{
  do
  {
    while($dRow = $stmt->fetch())
    {
       // Iterate rows
    }
    if (!$stmt->nextRowset())
      break;
  } while (true);
  return false;
}
```

I've also heard that using `$stmt->closeCursor()` PRIOR to the execute statement works, but my experience is that it closes the connection.